# Enabling OAuth on Gitlab for Tower integration

Tags: oauth, gitlab

According to [GitLab's documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/integration/oauth_provider.html#oauth-applications-in-admin-area) I should be able to enable OAuth through **Profile Settings > Applications**,

However, when I access my **Profile Settings**, I do not see a link for **Applications**

[image: screenshot from my account]

I would like to get this done in order to integrate my account into the Tower git client for Mac.

Comment: What version of GitLab are you running? It looks fairly old. You can check using the `?` link to the right of the search box.

Comment: @Chris Its GitLab 7.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab 7.0.0 is [very old](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/releases/tag/v7.0.0) (released June 20, 2014). You should consider upgrading to get new features, but more importantly to get security and bug fixes.

In any case, it is too old to support OAuth, which appears to have been [introduced in version 7.7](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/01/22/gitlab-7-7-and-ci-5-4-released/):

> The biggest new features in GitLab Community Edition are the **GitHub importer** and **OAuth support**.